# After npm install --save bootstrap I can't find bootstrap.min.css

Tags: css, npm

As the title suggests, I'm following a video, I do the command as it says there but then I can't find bootstrap.min.css anywhere, and I can't find anything on internet about it. I'm getting the following files:

[image]

I could manually download it or use the CDN but I'd really like to install it as an npm module to follow the course.

Comment: `bootstrap.min` is `bootstrap.min.css`

Comment: Good Lord, I forgot I reinstalled the OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically Windows doesn't show you the file extension by default, you have to set it Like:

[image]

As you're seeing `bootstrap.min`, that is the `bootstrap.min.css` file without extension.

Cheer you!

Answer (score 3):

You already have `bootstrap.min.css`, windows do not show format of the file, as you can see in front of `bootstrap.min` in `type` column it's mentioned `Cascading Style Sheet` that is CSS.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause was the fact that my angular project wasn't finding the file because it had the wrong path:
in angular.json I put this path:

> "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"

which was copy pasted from the video, but in fact it had to be

> "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"